# Scroll an element on drag in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, drag

I am trying to mimic an implementation of drag on scroll that I have come across in pure js but in react which drags an element on scroll (horizontally - vertically) but it looks like there is some stuff to be done here. Here is the implementation of the onmousedown, onmouseup, onmousemove on the div that is the target one:

`<div ref={scrollableDiv} onMouseUp={onMouseUpHandler} onMouseDown={onMouseDownHandler} onMouseMove={onMouseMoveHandler} />`

And here is the handlers:

```
 let pos = { top: 0, left: 0, x: 0, y: 0 };

const onMouseMoveHandler = (e) => {
    // How far the mouse has been moved
    const dx = e.clientX - pos.x;
    const dy = e.clientY - pos.y;

    console.log({ emousemove: e, tableBody, dx, dy });

    // Scroll the element
    scrollableDiv.current.scrollTop = pos.top - dy;
    scrollableDiv.current.scrollLeft = pos.left - dx;
};

const onMouseUpHandler = () => {
    scrollableDiv.current.style.cursor = "grab";
    scrollableDiv.current.style.removeProperty("user-select");
};

const onMouseDownHandler = (e) => {
    pos = {
        // The current scroll
        left: scrollableDiv.current.scrollLeft,
        top: scrollableDiv.current.scrollTop,
        // Get the current mouse position
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
    };

    // Change the cursor and prevent user from selecting the text
    scrollableDiv.current.style.cursor = "grabbing";
    scrollableDiv.current.style.userSelect = "none";
};
```

The code doesn't work except for the part of the styles. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.